# How can I hide a database column in the entity model?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

I'm using the Entity Framework 4 and have a question:

I have a password column in my database that I want to manage using custom SQL. So I don't want the model to know anything about it.

I've tried deleting the property in the Mapping Details window, but then I got a compilation error:

> Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 1660:Column User.Password in table User must be mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable.

So, I made the column nullable in the database and updated the model. Now I get this error:

> Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 1660:No mapping specified for properties User.Password, User.Salt in Set Users.
>   An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>     Entity is type [UserDirectoryModel.User]

Any ideas please?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to fix this is to create a view of your user table that does not include the password column. Then use the view in your model rather than the table.

Answer (score 12):

You could just mark the Property as Private using the Properties pane in the EDMX designer: Under the code generation option it has Getter and Setter options that you can change from Public to Private.

Comment: Thanks. That's the quick solution.